None of my messaging apps give me notifications anymore
This morning my wife sent me a series of messages on Telegram X.  I didn't get any notifications.
This has become the usual for most of my messaging apps on Android.  (I have Android 14.)  I have Telegram X, Threema, Discord, and Teams.  Teams is the only one that consistently shows notifications; the other three often get messages and don't notify about it at all.  (Standard text messaging also works.)
I've obviously checked the usual places, notification settings, battery settings, etc.
Not sure if it's related, but I also find that my Polar watch no longer background-syncs with Android.  I have to be running the Polar app for it to sync properly; otherwise it can't connect.
Is this a known issue in current versions of Android?  Is Android intentionally disabling these apps to save battery life at the expense of functionality or something?
How can I fix this (meaning, get my notifications as expected)?

Most messenger use Google Push Notifications (AKA Firebase Cloud messaging). Such messages are handled by Google Play Services on your device. Check this system app and may be try to clear it's app data.
